# specs2でテスト実行前に共通の処理をしたい

Tags: scala, playframework

ログイン前提のAPIたちのテストケースを作成したいのですが、前段としてログイン処理が必要になります。
テスト実行前にログイン処理をして、その戻り値(セッションID)を使い回してテストケースを実行する必要があるのですがどうすればよいでしょうか？
ログイン処理は一回だけで済ませたいです。
このまま実行すると`Could not create an instance of HogeSpec`とインスタンス化できないと言われてしまいます。

```
class HogeSpec extends Specification {

  // このuserSessionIdを各テストケースで使いたい
  val userSessionId = BaseSpec.beforeAuth()

  "hogeAPIのテスト" should {
    "ステータス200が返ってくること" in {
      // do something
      // userSessionIdを使ってAPIをテストしたい
    }
  }

  "fugaAPIのテスト" should {
    "ステータス200が返ってくること" in {
      // do something
      // userSessionIdを使ってAPIをテストしたい
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

自己解決しました。

`lazy`で遅延評価にすることでエラーの回避ができました。
これでuserSessionIdを使い回せるようになりました。
特別`BeforeExample`などを使う必要はありませんでした。

```
- val userSessionId = BaseSpec.beforeAuth()
+ lazy val userSessionId = BaseSpec.beforeAuth()
```

こちらの解答が参考になったので共有します。
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21830495/specs2-could-not-create-an-instance